# Large(ish) django application architecture

Tags: python, django

How does one properly structure a larger django website such as to retain testability and maintainability?

In the best django spirit (I hope) we started out by not caring too much about decoupling between different parts of our website. We did separate it into different apps, but those depend rather directly upon each other, through common use of model classes and direct method calls.

This is getting quite entangled. For example, one of our actions/services looks like this:

```
def do_apply_for_flat(user, flat, bid_amount):
    assert can_apply(user, flat)
    application = Application.objects.create(
        user=user, flat=flat, amount=bid_amount,
        status=Application.STATUS_ACTIVE)

    events.logger.application_added(application)
    mails.send_applicant_application_added(application)
    mails.send_lessor_application_received(application)
    return application
```

The function does not only perform the actual business process, no, it also handles event logging and sending mails to the involved users. I don't think there's something inherently wrong with this approach. Yet, it's getting more and more difficult to properly reason about the code and even test the application, as it's getting harder to separate parts intellectually and programmatically.

So, my question is, how do the big boys structure their applications such that:

1. Different parts of the application can be tested in isolation
2. Testing stays fast by only enabling parts that you really need for a specific test
3. Code coupling is reduced

My take on the problem would be to introduce a centralized signal hub (just a bunch of django signals in a single python file) which the single django apps may publish or subscribe to. The above example function would publish an `application_added` event, which the mails and events apps would listen to. Then, for efficient testing, I would disconnect the parts I don't need. This also increases decoupling considerably, as services don't need to know about sending mails at all.

But, I'm unsure, and thus very interested in what's the accepted practice for these kind of problems.

Comment: You probably don't want to use signals for mailing. If sending mails are your functional requirements, the code for sending mails *should* be in the service/view code, and not hidden away in a signal subscriber somewhere you can't see.

Comment: Yeah well, but I have to start somewhere, don't I? Sending Mails is done in a celery task to keep thing snappy, so it is a bit 'hidden' anyway. Also, the mails only need to be sent eventually.

Comment: sending email after application registration is your functional requirement, how the email is actually sent out is implementation detail. Passing the actual mail sending to celery is ok, that's explicit not hidden (which is good). What you don't want is to hide the function call to `mails.send_*` behind a signal.

Comment: Yes, I think so. From your experience, is it ok to use signals for a lot of these things in django? Id' mostly use signals in a 'robust' mode, i.e., I wouldn't much care for the result. Functionality wise this would be used for cache updates, sending mails, logging, post-processing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer some parts of your app to different microservices. This will make some parts of your app focused on doing one or two things right (e.g. event logging, emails). Code coupling is also reduced and different parts of the site can be tested in isolation as well.

> The microservice architecture style involves developing a single application as a collection of smaller services that communicates usually via an API.

You might need to use a smaller framework like Flask.

**Resources:**

For more information on microservices click here:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html
http://aurelavramescu.blogspot.com/2014/06/user-microservice-python-way.html

Comment: Yes, microservices are certainly a viable option, thank you for the links. I agree that Flask might be a better fit for this. Alas, when considering our current app's codebase, it's gonna be a HUGE step and nearly complete rewrite of the server side code. I wonder if there's a less drastic option?

Comment: The rewrite is better done in iterations since this is a major change in your architecture (and mentality of adding features). Another option is to only start microservices to new components or modules.

Comment: @Nuschk: you should not be doing a huge rewrite of your application. Microservice can be deployed by carving out parts of an existing application, one service at a time.

Comment: You might be right, I'd need to think about that. Still, the deployment scheme would need to change a lot (we still have a single container atm), which is probably also why I'm hesitant.

Comment: Although there is some good advice from everyone, I'm selecting this as answer because I think it most closely matches my question (for which there doesn't seem to be a unique answer anyways). Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, you should mock your dependencies. The logging and mailing component, for example, should be mocked during unit testing of the views. I would usually use [python-mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock), this allows your views to be tested independently of the logging and mailing component, and vice versa. Just assert that your views are calling the right service calls and mock the return value/side effect of the service call.

You should also avoid touching the database when doing tests. Instead try to use as much in memory objects as possible, instead of `Application.objects.create()`, defer the `save()` to the caller, so that you can test the services without having to actually have the Application in the database. Alternatively, patch out the `save()` method, so it won't actually save, but that's much more tedious.

Comment: That's a good point about mocking. I'm still a bit puzzled of how I best create mockable components in the django environment. I somehow see myself just writing Service classes and place them as singletons in the django apps. This way they would be mockable, right? Or is it more elaborate than this?

You're right about saving objects affecting performance. Yet, this might also introduce subtle bugs that won't be discovered by tests (been there done that...), so I'm a bit uncertain there.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to brake down your big task into smaller classes. Connect them with usual method calls or Django signals.

If you feel that the sub-tasks are independent enough, you can implement them as several Django applications in the same project. See the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/), which describes relation between applications and projects.

Comment: Thanks. IMO we've already pretty much done that. It's not really that our tasks are big, they are entangled. E.g., our flats app triggers the geocoding app, which queries and writes to the flat app's models directly. There's no distinctive seam on which to separate the two. U feel that the django tutorial (which I've read a few times) doesn't really give an architectural guideline.